# NuGet restore failed JetBrains Package

Tags: jenkins, nuget-package-restore

When I build my .NET Solution in Jenkins and try to restore NuGet packages before the actual MSBuild step I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5): error : Package JetBrains.Annotations, version 11.1.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [PATHLENGHT = 86]
```

I'm using MSBuild 15 and NuGet Windows x86 Commandline nuget.exe v4.7.0

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this was a .Net Standard Project, i need to add this command to make it a successful build:

/t:restore